# Range.Copy with user imputed variables

Tags: excel, vba

Just trying to copy a section of data over from one workbook to another workbook to avoid having to use indirect references. Area being copied needs to be variable. Index and Index2 are A1 D77 style. Running the below I get a "Copy method of Range class failed." What do I have wrong?

```
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, index As String, index2 As 
String

directory = TextBox2
fileName = TextBox1
index = TextBox4
index2 = TextBox5

Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(index & ":" & index2).Copy _
    Workbooks("Copy of Worksheet Template for Monthly 
    report.xlsm").Worksheets("Data")

Workbooks(fileName).Close
fileName = Dir()

Worksheets("Tables").Select
```

Comment: What's the issue? You haven't asked a question...

Comment: What values make up `Index` and `index2`?

Comment: Figure out what type of range you are goign to use... `Range(A2:A4)` or Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(4,1))` are significantly different in syntax... you have `Range(index,index2)` which looks like you are using the wrong syntax... if you have `index = a2` and `index2 = a4` then you can use `Range(index & ":" & index2)`... gotta know what values are being used to make sense of how your copied and pasted ranges will look.

Comment: index and index 2 are A2:A4  style. I tried Range(index & ":" & index2) and got a "Copy method of Range class failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, index As String, index2 As String, 
DataRNG As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = TextBox2
fileName = TextBox1
index = TextBox4
index2 = TextBox5
DataRNG = index & ":" & index2


Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(DataRNG).Copy _
    Workbooks("Monthly Service and Parts Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")

Workbooks(fileName).Close

Worksheets("Tables").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send range address

```
Dim DataRng As Range
Set DataRng = Range(index, index2)
DataRng.Select

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(DataRng.Address).Copy _
Workbooks("Copy of Worksheet Template for Monthly 
report.xlsm").Worksheets("Data")
```

Also you should be specifying the `index` and `index2` as `string` only if you saying it is `A1` or `D77`, otherwise you should use `integers` or `long` and if you are using just numbers then you can specify the range by using `index = cells(row,col)` & `index2 = cells(row2,col2)`

Comment: index and index 2 are A1 D77 style.

Comment: There should be enough code there to help you build what you need. Comment if it is not working and what the error is. Also please mark the answer as solved if this does solve your question.